# Swift 4: UI fails to update after device rotation

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I want to change my `bearImageView`'s width and height to 100 when going from portrait -> landscape, and to 200 when going the opposite direction.

Inside the `setupLayout` I am calling deactivating and then activating the constraint on `widthAnchor` and `heightAnchor`. So I am expecting it to change the width and height.

**Problem: It goes to 100, but it does not change back to 200.**
Why would this happen?

This is the code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // closure objects
    let bearImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "bear_first")) // type `image literal` and double click
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // enable autolayout
        return imageView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()            
        view.addSubview(bearImageView) // display image        
        setupLayout(imageView: bearImageView) // apply constraints
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
            print("landscape")
            setupLayout(imageView: bearImageView) // apply constraints                
        } else {
            print("portrait")
            setupLayout(imageView: bearImageView) // apply constraints                
        }
    }

    private func setupLayout(imageView: UIImageView){

        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape == true {
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = false
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = false
            imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
            print("changed to landscape")

        } else {
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = false
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = false
            imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
            print("changed to portrait")
        }

    }
```

This is the error.

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000031923a0 UIImageView:0x7fbf72508060.width == 200   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000031e4730 UIImageView:0x7fbf72508060.width == 100   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000031923a0 UIImageView:0x7fbf72508060.width == 200   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the `constraint` method creates *new* for your image view.

When you first call `setupLayout` in `viewDidLoad`, width and height constraints of 200 are added to the image view. Then you rotate the device to change to landscape. `setupLayout` is called again. This time it adds width and height constraints of 100, *but it does not deactivate the constraints with constant 200 that you previously added*. Doing this line:

```
imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = false
```

Creates a new inactive constraint, *not* deactivates an old one.

What you should do is to store the width  and height constraints as properties of `ViewController`:

```
var widthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

And in `setupLayout`, assign to those properties:

```
private func setupLayout(imageView: UIImageView){
    widthConstraint = imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
    heightConstraint = imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
    widthConstraint.isActive = true
    heightConstraint.isActive = true
    imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true

}
```

And you should only call `setupLayout` once.

Then you create another method called `updateConstraints` that update the constants of `widthConstraint` and `heightConstraint`:

```
private func updateConstraints() {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        heightConstraint.constant = 100
        widthConstraint.constant = 100
    } else {
        heightConstraint.constant = 200
        widthConstraint.constant = 200
    }
}
```

Call this in `viewWillTransitionToSize` instead of `setupLayout`.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it should be something like that! By the way, these two lines were missing from your setupLayout(). `            widthConstraintImage.isActive = true
            heightConstraintImage.isActive = true`